# how to import the aliased sqlalchemy function

Tags: sqlalchemy

In [the SQLAlchemy Tutorial](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/tutorial.html#using-literal-sql)

an example uses `aliased`:

```
>>> from sqlalchemy import func
>>> ua = aliased(User)
>>> q = q.from_self(User.id, User.name, ua.name).\
...     filter(User.name < ua.name).\
...     filter(func.length(ua.name) != func.length(User.name))
```

But it does not work in 0.6.1:

```
>>> from sqlalchemy import func

>>> ua = aliased(User)


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    ua = aliased(User)
NameError: name 'aliased' is not defined
>>> ua = aliased(User)


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    ua = aliased(User)
NameError: name 'aliased' is not defined
>>> ua = sqlalchemy.aliased(User)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    ua = sqlalchemy.aliased(User)
NameError: name 'sqlalchemy' is not defined
>>> import sqlalchemy
>>> ua = sqlalchemy.aliased(User)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    ua = sqlalchemy.aliased(User)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'aliased'
>>>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import aliased
```

[class sqlalchemy.orm.aliased](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/query.html?highlight=aliased#sqlalchemy.orm.aliased)